# Is there an equivalent of Node.js for .NET developers?

Tags: node.js

I'm a .NET developer and would like to use something like Node.js and run it in the Microsoft cloud. Is there an equivalent? I know Microsoft is helping port this over but no sign of when this will happen and I need something in the meantime.

Comment: Why not, you know, use node.js and a different cloud in the meantime?

Comment: @Dan - That's an option but my database already runs on SQL Azure and I'm afraid that if I put Node.js on the Amazon cloud I will take a performance hit which defeats the whole point. No?

Comment: Azure [added support for Node.js](http://www.readwriteweb.com/cloud/2012/01/cloud9-ide-to-enable-nodejs-ap.php) a couple of months ago. So you can use the real Node.js and run it in the Microsoft cloud.

Answer (score 7):

There's a couple of projects under way:

> https://github.com/dnewcome/Node.net
>
> https://github.com/Rduerden/Node.cs

I couldn't vouch for their completeness.

I'd also have a read of this post by Ayende, the comments are particularly interesting:

> http://ayende.com/blog/72705/node-cs

Answer (score 6):

Why would you need Node.js when .NET has supported event-driven async IO from the very beginning?  (Look at the all the *.Begin/*.End methods in the IO and web request classes).

Furthermore, the explicitly event-driven approach used by Node.js and the .NET APM (Asynchronous Programming Model) will soon be superceded by the async/await keywords in C#.  This has the benefit of producing much more readable code.

Answer (score 1):

Actually a port of node to windows is already underway and currently actively worked on. You can already download a windows build of node on the [official page](http://nodejs.org/#download). It is however still far from beeing production ready, but you should be able to play around with it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to look at [manos](https://github.com/jacksonh/manos) and it's [manifesto](http://jacksonh.tumblr.com/post/1159500924/manos-de-mono-the-manifesto) article.

Answer (score 0):

Hi i started the development of a Node.Cs like server with support for .NET MVC Controllers, Razor etc. Just to explain, is based on a system like Node.Js with few threads, without locks and with a queue of couroutines.

PS any suggestion or correction is welcome!

- [Documentation](http://www.kendar.org/?p=/dotnet/nodecs)
- [MvcMusicStore sample port on Node.Cs](https://github.com/endaroza/NodeCsMusicStore)
- [Packages on Nuget](http://www.nuget.org/packages?q=Node.Cs&prerelease=true)